# App freezes while download a file from server

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string

I am trying to download a txt file from server but app freezes a little bit while I am downloading the string :

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {



            let getPrice = try! String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://site.cin/price.txt")!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.price.text = getPrice


    }
```

I don't want to use AFNetwroking and etc ...

Comment: because you are running the download on the main thread, blocking the UI

Comment: But why you perform download explicitly in main thread? Use other thread instead, return to main thread only for UI update.

Comment: I just remove the main thread

Comment: You are still on the main thread. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let bgQueue = NSOperationQueue()

        bgQueue.addOperationWithBlock { 
            let getPrice = try! String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://site.cin/price.txt")!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.price.text = getPrice
        }
```

This codes runs in background and will not block your main thread so that app will not freeze.

Comment: The Simplest  solution !

Answer (score 3):

All the UI of your app is running on main thread. If you try to perform any network related task(which takes some seconds at least) on main thread then it will block main thread for that time of period. So, you should never perform this kind of task on main thread except `UI` related changes. so it's better to make asynchronous request for network call and update `UI` on main thread on completion.

You should do something like,

```
  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL( NSURL(string: "http://site.cin/price.txt")!) { (data, response, error) in

        var getprice = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 

            self.price.text = getPrice
        })

    }
```

Comment: You should explain what he's doing wrong instead of just posting code.

Comment: @VladimirNul there is enough explanations in comments

Comment: @VladimirNul :  In comments there is already explanation is given then also i have updated answer as per your suggestion... :)

Answer (score 1):

You are running on the main thread. Try this:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    let getPrice = try! String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://site.cin/price.txt")!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    self.price.text = getPrice

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         // update some UI
    }
}
```